# How to self draw a simple line

Tags: svg

How can I draw the following line in slow motion? I lots and lots of demos and tutorials on animating paths. But, I'm trying to create a line that slowly draws itself once.

```
<svg height="200" width="200">
    <line x1="10" y1="10 x2="30' y2="10" />
</svg>
```

EDIT
HERE IS THE SOLUTION I FOUND

```
    #path {
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1;
        stroke-dasharray: 300px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 300px;
        animation-name: draw;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    @keyframes draw{
        to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
    }


    <line id="path" x1="300" y1="120" x2="300" y2="350" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" 
        stroke-dasharray="300px" stroke-dashoffset="300" />
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is a `<path>` or a `<line>`. The standard `stroke-dasharray` technique will work for both.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I just followed along with what the tutorial had for paths. Here is the markup I used: <line id="path" x1="300" y1="120" x2="300" y2="350" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" 
    stroke-dasharray="300px" stroke-dashoffset="300" />

Comment: For best effect, you generally make the dash array and dash offset the same length as the path or line.  In your case that is 350-120 = 230.